# Angular 2 - remove ngFor item that use async pipe

Tags: angular

How to remove item from *ngFor that use async pipe

I have this code

```
 <tg-template
    [template]="template"
    *ngFor="let template of templates$ | async">
  </tg-template>
```

and I want to be able to remove item when user click on delete button for example.

The problem is I don't have reference to the templates array I only have the templates$ observable.

Comment: Your question is not informational please add more detail to it.

Comment: Don't use async, and store the array on your component instead of the observable.